# TIJ4 - compareTo() and inheritance - Tuple.java, exercise 28 from chapter 17

Tags: java

Solution guide for TIJ4 for exercise 28 from chapter 17 says:

> When  a class  extends a  concrete Comparable  class (as  T3<A,B,C>
>     extends T2<A,B>  in the  original program),  and adds  a significant
>     field,  there is  no way  to simultaneously  implement compareTo()
>     correctly. (...) The same holds true for equals()"

I did this exercise using inheritance as it was used in "original
program" and it works as well (?). In exercise some needs to implement
equals() method and Comparable interface.

```
public class TwoTuple<A extends Comparable, B extends Comparable> 
    implements Comparable {
  public final A first;
  public final B second;
  public TwoTuple(A a, B b) { 
    first = a; 
    second = b;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "(" + toString2() + ")";
  }
  protected String toString2() { 
    return first + ", " + second;
  }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o != null && 
      o.getClass() == getClass() && 
      (first == null 
        ? getClass().cast(o).first == null 
        : first.equals(getClass().cast(o).first)) &&
      (second == null 
        ? getClass().cast(o).second == null
        : second.equals(getClass().cast(o).second));
  }
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    if(first != null) {
      result = result * 37 + first.hashCode();
    }
    return second == null ? result : result * 37 + second.hashCode();
  }
  public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if(o.getClass() != getClass()) { 
      throw new ClassCastException();
    }
    int comparation = first.compareTo(getClass().cast(o).first);
    return comparation != 0 
      ? comparation 
      : second.compareTo(getClass().cast(o).second);
  }
}

public class ThreeTuple<A extends Comparable, B extends Comparable, C extends Comparable>
    extends TwoTuple<A, B>  {
  public final C third;
  public ThreeTuple(A a, B b, C c) {
    super(a, b);
    third = c;
  }
  protected String toString2() {
    return super.toString2() + ", " + third;
  }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return super.equals(o) && 
      (third == null 
        ? getClass().cast(o).third == null 
        : third.equals(getClass().cast(o).third));
  }
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = super.hashCode();
    return third == null ? result : result * 37 + third.hashCode();
  }
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Object o) {
    int comparation = super.compareTo(o);
    return comparation != 0 
      ? comparation 
      : third.compareTo(getClass().cast(o).third);
  }
}
```

Is my solution correct or I missed something?

To make it working I needed to skip generics implementing Comparable interface, so not this way:

```
TwoTuple(...) implements Comparable<TwoTuple> {
(...)
int compareTo(TwoTuple o) {
```

but just:

```
TwoTuple(...) implements Comparable {
(...)
 int compareTo(Object o) {
```

Maybe this is wrong statement which not obeying docs (?).

-- 
regards
Pawel

Comment: Better try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're writing in such a way that an instances of the base class and an instance of a derived classes cannot be compared using `compareTo`. That might work well for many scenarios, but it's not necessarily what the author meant by "simultaneously implement correctly".